# Reading XYZ with tiles in tif format using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, xyz-tiles

I am trying to set up a XYZ server for scientific data. The server is able to send both PNG and TIF images. The TIF format is used to get numeric values, whereas the PNG is used for visualization purposes.

I would like to be able to interact, within QGIS, with the TIF layer (change color palette, perform some computations in areas, etc.). However, I am not even able to see the TIF layer (works perfectly for the PNG layer).

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Why aren't you able to see the tifs?

Comment: What/where is this server? can you give the url so we can help more.